# Project texture from one object to another

Tags: texturing

[image: project texture from one object to another]
I want to project the ring with red texture to the monkey, the ring surrounds the monkey, I want the color or texture of the ring to be reflected in the monkey.

Comment: are you talking about a reflection (like a mirror) or a texture with a red stripe? If you're talking about reflection and if you're using Eevee you need to use Light Probe > Reflection Cubemap

Comment: I mean a texture, I chose red to better draw the example, but it can be any texture.
the texture is in the ring, the ring is a mesh. but it can be any mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Too many options ... please be more specific :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use 'Transfer Mesh Data' with a very big 'Ray Radius'

1. Select Monkey first, then Shift select the ring
2. Search for 'Transfer Mesh Data'
3. Select 'UVs' (I used Vertex colors for this test, UV's should work the same)
4. Set 'Ray Radius' to a very high value (bigger than bounding box of your scene,I think will cover it)
5. Experiment with different'Face Corner Mapping' options.
   [image]